# OAuth 2.0 implementation in Mule

Tags: oauth-2.0, mule, mule-studio, mule-component, raml

I am working on a project in which I need to expose some of its method over web service and that I am doing using Mule by following RAML and to implement security, OAuth 2.0 has been proposed. I am able to validate the client for its 'client_id' and 'client_secret' but for that I have given the credentials in configuration file only. Now I need to fetch the client details from database. I tried using 'preFlow-ref' and another flow is being called where I am able to retrieve 'client_id' and 'client_secret' but don't know how to give callback to OAuth.

```
 <spring:beans>
     <spring:bean id="oauthTokenStore" name="oauthTokenStore" class="database_connection.MyClientStore"/>
 </spring:beans>

 <oauth2-provider:config 
     name="oauth2Provider"
     providerName="TweetBook"
     supportedGrantTypes="CLIENT_CREDENTIALS"
     preFlow-ref="apiFlow1"
     host="localhost"
     port="8083"
     authorizationEndpointPath="tweetbook/api/authorize"
     accessTokenEndpointPath="tweetbook/api/token"
     scopes="READ_PROFILE WRITE_PROFILE READ_BOOKSHELF WRITE_BOOKSHELF">
 </oauth2-provider:config>

 <apikit:config name="Router" raml="src/main/api/api.raml" consoleEnabled="true" consolePath="console" doc:name="Router"/>

 <flow name="apiFlow1">          
     <set-variable variableName="client_id" value="1234567890abcd" doc:name="Client id"/>
     <logger message="entered DB flow" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
     <db:select config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
         <db:dynamic-query><![CDATA[select client_secret from table1 where client_id = #[flowVars.client_Id]]]></db:dynamic-query>
    </db:select>
    <logger message="exit db flow" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
 </flow>
```

Comment: Can you add the code to give more understanding ?

Comment: Hi Naveen, actually I have seen that if I am using database connector in preflow then control doesn't go back to OAuth provider and u can see the code snippet I have appended in question.